# How to implement open link in new tab in browser using angular?

Tags: angular

I have an angular application which has some users. After successful user login, user's data is saved in token in local storage in browser. There are some menus which user can use to view data after login which are working completely fine. But I get logged out of my application when I right click on one of menu and click open a link in new tab. So how do I implement open a link in new tab functionality in browser without getting logged out and be able to view same data in new tab after pressing open a link in new tab? Any suggestion would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was saving token and user details coming from server side in session storage. Session storage only works for a single tab and will expire instantly if it is tried to share with another tab. I went through this article https://medium.com/@marciomariani/sharing-sessionstorage-between-tabs-5b6f42c6348c After replacing session storage with local storage issue related to opening application in multiple tab is resolved. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this:

```
<a class="main-item" (click)="onNavigate()">Go to URL</a>

OR

<button class="main-item" (click)="onNavigate()">Go to URL</button>

in TS file:

onNavigate(){
  // your logic here.... like set the url 
  const url = 'https://www.google.com';
  window.open(url, '_blank');
}

OR

<a [routerLink]="['somthing']" target="_blank" class="FullViewLink">FullView </a>

You can target="_blank" in routerLink.
```

Comment: Seems unnecessarily complicated for something that can be accomplished without Angular entirely - just use href instead of routerLink and target=_blank

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with contextmenu event,
like:

```
<div (contextmenu)="onRightClick($event)" 
  menu
</div>
```

I got help from this article, when I was in need, check this out. surely it Helps.

https://marco.dev/angular-right-click-menu